# Paypal Adaptive Payment: Wrong Store

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I didn't modify anything in my config, after getting the `responseEnvelope->ack === SUCCESS` and a `preapprovalKey`, the client is redirected to 
`https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-preapproval&preapprovalkey=[PA-...]`
But since few days, the client gets a random Store, or a "This preapproval has already been processed. Please visit your PayPal Preapproval Overview to see the details."

I guess this correlated with the [recent changes from the sandox](https://devblog.paypal.com/sandbox-account-linking/) but still dont know what to do.

I'm using [paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php).
Reverting to `$SDK_VERSION = "3.9.1"` didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your paypal cookies! Fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks, it redirects to the correct store again. And the sandbox is back as well. I guess there was something wrong on the Paypal side.

Comment: Argh! It still does not work. It randomly redirect to another store. At least I'm sure it's not a Paypal feature ;)